# Numeric formatting in SQL report (local, rdlc)

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc, reporting-services

I have a requirement to show numeric values in a client side report with decimal places only if those decimal places are used. The source data is a Decimal data type populated from an SQL money column.

For example:

- 28.0000 is to be shown as "28"
- 2.5000 is to be shown as "2.5"
- 2.5500 is to be shown as "2.55"

I cannot find a formatting option to do this. The nearest I have gotten in "#,###.####", but this still shows the decimal point even when there is nothing after it.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your data field is UnitPrice, then you can apply an expression on the format of the text box ( *right click ===> text box properties => Number => Custom => press on fx*) showing  the value for the field like this one.

```
=IIF( Floor(Fields!UnitPrice.Value) = Fields!UnitPrice.Value,"#,0;(#,0)",
IIF(Floor(Fields!UnitPrice.Value * 10) = Fields!UnitPrice.Value * 10,"#,0.0;(#,0.0)","#,0.00;(#,0.00)")
)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example as Amount is your field

In the expression screen just add this following line.

```
Format(CDec(Fields!Amount.Value),"#.##")
```